# 255 characters limit in xlookup and choose function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was trying to use a non-contiguous xlookup with the choose function inside of it but it seems it doesn't return the content of cells with more than 255 characters (#VALUE!). Is there any way to work this around ?

Here's the formula :

=XLOOKUP(O4&,E4:E47,CHOOSE({1,2,3},E4:E47,F4:F47,K4:K47))

I've looked here and there on the web but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem using choose for joining of non-contiguous arrays or columns**

It appears if you use an array index in CHOOSE e.g. CHOOSE( {1,2}, ...) it truncates the returned values to a maximum of 255 characters, at least for text values. Ironically if you use a scalar index e.g. CHOOSE(2, ...), there is seemingly no character limit.

One workaround here might be to use Google sheets, as not only would CHOOSE likely not have this specific bug, but you can actually just build up the non-contiguous matrix using `{ E4:E47, F4:F47,K4:K47 }`.

**Excel solution for lookup with non-contiguous return array or table**

A. One obvious solution is to use separate XLOOKUP functions for each return column.

```
=XLOOKUP(O4,E4:E47,E4:E47)
=XLOOKUP(O4,E4:E47,F4:F47)
=XLOOKUP(O4,E4:E47,K4:K47)
```

This is unfortunately every inefficient with x3 more lookup searches required for the same search value. Not to mention the difficulty if the number of return columns changes.

B. If you can lump all the return columns in one range e.g. E4:K47, you can use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(O4,E4:K47,{1,2,7},FALSE)
```

C. Or INDEX into XLOOKUP returning a whole row array:

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(O4,E4:E47,E4:K47),,{1,2,7})   ...which may be faster
```

D. Lastly, if you data is truly scattered and non-contiguous, use MATCH & INDEX to build your own LOOKUP function:

```
=INDEX((E4:E47,F4:F47,K4:K47),MATCH(O4,E4:E47,0),,{1,2,3})
```

The beauty of this solution is that INDEX naturally allows you to specify non-contiguous areas (e.g. hold CTRL when making a selection).

I am still not sure which one of these solutions A to D will be the fastest. I suspect using static arrays as function arguments might just execute the same functions multiple times. My money is on D or C.

**NB.** For pre-Office 365 remember to finish the array formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (CSE) whilst editing multiple cells equal to the length of the return array. In Office 365, the formula will automatically *spill* over into adjacent cells.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer.
Like you said, I think the best way would be to use option C or D.
To add some more context : I'm trying to do this in Excel, without having to move any column. I'm not sure how it could be done while using INDEX and MATCH.

Here's a picture to show more precisely what I'm experimenting on : [link](https://prnt.sc/26j337y)

My goal is to retrieve the information found on the left side and put it on the right side. I have tried the following formula but without success : 

=INDEX((A:A,C:C,F:F),MATCH(L2,F:F,0),,{1,2,3})

Comment: @Adeval I think you just made a typo. You are searching for the letter in the ID column, rather than the letter column. So the formula in M2 should rather be `=INDEX((C:C,F:F),MATCH(L2,A:A,0),,{2,1})`

Comment: @Adeval, oh and please do remember to checkmark the solution so others may know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks for your solution ! It works perfectly !